# how to extract text between tags using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract text from the following html structure:

```
<div class= "story-body story-content">
 <p>
  <br>
  "the text I want to get"
  <a href= "http://...>
  <br>
  "the text I want to get"
  <a href="http:// ... >
  .
  .
```

I've already extracted the hyper links, but I don't know how to extract the text as well. So far I tried:

```
names = []
for div in soup3.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "story-body story-content"}):
    for t in div.find_all('br'):
        t = t.get_text()
        names.append(t)
```

But I only get:

```
[<br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for div in soup3.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "story-body story-content"}):
    text_list = [text for text in div.stripped_strings]
```

use `stripped_string` to get all the non-empty string under a tag

The `<br>` tag inserts a single line break. it does not contain any text.

Comment: Thanks, but how can i only extract the text, not the http://? I used the code but it seems to put everything within a list, which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = """
<div class= "story-body story-content">
<p>
<br>
"the text I want to get"
<a href= "http://...>
<br>
"the text I want to get"
<a href="http:// ... >
"""
s = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
s.br.nextSibling
```

Will return:

```
'\n  "the text I want to get"\n  '
```

or:

```
s.br.nextSibling.strip()
```